# JList created in Netbeans won't allow me to addElement

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist

This is the automatically created code when adding the Jlist in Netbeans design mode:

```
jListResult = new javax.swing.JList();

jListResult.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jListResult);
```

I don't understand why an object of type Jlist would not be able to use the method .addElement How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`addElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement-E-)  is provided by the `DefaultListModel` not the `JList` itself

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList jListResult = new JList(model);
model.addElement(...);
```

Comment: Alright well, how would I go about fixing this then?   
I tried adding :


    DefaultListModel info = new DefaultListModel();

    jListResult.setModel(info);

Comment: How about `info.addElement(...)`